# Is there any way to make a lat using cons in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket, nested-lists

I'm having this simple piece of code, constructing a list of numbers:

```
#lang scheme

(define pseudofizzbuzz (lambda (x)
             (cond
               ((zero? x) (quote ()))
               ((or (integer? (/ x 3)) (integer? (/ x 5))) (cons (quote ()) (pseudofizzbuzz (- x 1))))
               (else (cons x (pseudofizzbuzz (- x 1)))))))

(define reverselist (lambda (lat)
                  (cond
                    ((null? lat) (quote ()))
                    (else
                     (cons (reverselist (cdr lat)) (list (car lat))))))) 


(reverselist (pseudofizzbuzz 10))
```

And the result I get is:

```
 ((((((((((() 1) 2) ()) 4) ()) ()) 7) 8) ()) ())
```

But what I want of course is:

```
(1 2 4 7 8)
```

Is there any way to do it in scheme? I'm using DrRacket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(cons an-element a-list)` to extend `a-list` with a new element `an-element`:

```
#lang racket

(define pseudofizzbuzz
  (lambda (x)
    (cond
      ((zero? x)
       (quote ()))
      ((or (integer? (/ x 3)) (integer? (/ x 5)))
       (pseudofizzbuzz (- x 1)))
      (else
       (cons x (pseudofizzbuzz (- x 1)))))))

(define reverselist
  (lambda (lat)
    (cond
      ((null? lat) 
       (quote ()))
      (else        
       (cons (reverselist (cdr lat)) (list (car lat))))))) 

(pseudofizzbuzz 10)
```

This produces the results in reverse order, so

```
(reverse (pseudofizzbuzz 10))
```

will give you the elements in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Already found the answer:

```
 (define (flatten x)
    (cond ((null? x) '())
          ((not (pair? x)) (list x))
          (else (append (flatten (car x))
                        (flatten (cdr x))))))
```